# Testing on angular $resource query shows error of ngResourceProvider not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<script src="/library/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angularjs.js"></script>
<script src="/library/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/library/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script>
var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
app.service('Greeter', ['$resource',function($resource){
  return $resource(
    'http://123.com/processor.php',
    {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
    {
      query: {method:'JSON_CALLBACK',isArray:true}
    });
}]);

app
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Greeter',
  function($scope,Greeter){
  alert("yes");
  $scope.greet = function(){
    alert("greetttt");
    Greeter.query({name:this.name}, function(response){
      alert(response.greeting);
    });
  };
}]);
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Your name: 
    <input type="text" name="name" value="World"/>
    <button ng-click="greet()">greet</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The PHP file simply throw out a JSON array, but I saw chrome inspectors tells me that:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- Greeter
```

I wonder if there is any syntax error? As the PHP do throw out a valid JSON array.

Thanks

***Update1----***
I update the code shows that I loaded the resource and angular in the right order.
After Bielski's fix, still, there is error shows (same error)
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- Greeter
**Update 2**
After runTarm fix, The only trouble now seems the way I reference Greeter is not correct...
    ReferenceError: Greeter is not defined
        at Scope.$scope.greet (http://123.com/index-query.php:21:5)
which represent this line:
    Greeter.query({name:this.name}, function(response){

**Update 3**

After suggested adding Greeter ad resource, still, the error of below will appear:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.greet (http://123.com/index-query.php:21:13)
```

Seemingly something is wrong between these 3 lines

```
$scope.greet = function(){
    alert("greetttt");
    Greeter.query({name:this.name}, function(response){
```

Comment: Did you include the `angular-resource.js` script?

Comment: @runTarm I did. I also update the question, please take a look. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the `ngResource` in your module's dependency list like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
```

Another thing is about the `greet()` function, when you bind a function in `ng-click` like this:

```
<button ng-click="greet()">
```

Angular will look for the `greet()` function in the controller's scope, but you define the `greet()` in the controller instance itself.

One way is to move the `greet()` function into the `$scope` like this:

```
app
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Greeter',
    function($scope, Greeter){
      alert("yes");
      $scope.greet = function(){
        alert("greetttt");
        Greeter.query({name:this.name}, function(response){
          alert(response.greeting);
        });
      };
  }]);
```

Comment: I update the question, however, now it complain that Greeter is not defined. I thought it was I did not reference it in the controller, but even after I did , the error will still be there. Thank you very much ahead of time!

Comment: You forget the `Greeter` parameter (after `$scope`) in the controller function.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect your new code. I mean `.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Greeter', function($scope, Greeter){`

Comment: I am really confused, it still the same, I updated the code again to reflect changes you proposed, but have the same error. something seems wrong with the scope

Comment: You have to use `app.factory('Greeter',` instead of `.service('Greeter'`. I bet you would found another errors, what is the `method: 'JSON_CALLBACK'` mean? It should be 'GET', 'POST' or another valid HTTP verbs.

Comment: I really appreciate your assistance! wonderful job! THUMB UP+++! : D

Answer (score 1):

The $resource provider isn't being loaded and/or referenced correctly. Two things:

First, you need to make sure that the file 'angular-resource.js' is being loaded in your page, and that it appears in the list of scripts to be loaded BEFORE you load your app.

Second, try setting your service up like this:

```
app.service('Greeter', ['$resource', function($resource){
  return $resource(
    'http://123.com/processor.php', 
    {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
    {
      query: {method:'JSON_CALLBACK',isArray:true}
    });
}]);
```

This will give you protection from minification errors and it is sometimes eaiser to spot which providers are missing using this format.

Comment: I fixed accordingly, but still the same error. I can not find reason why... Please help thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add Greeter to the controller function's arguments

```
app
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Greeter',
  function($scope, Greeter){
  alert("yes");
  $scope.greet = function(){
    alert("greetttt");
    Greeter.query({name:this.name}, function(response){
      alert(response.greeting);
    });
  };
}]);
```